# Why are some questions displayed in red?

Tags: support

Right now I am looking at the "highest voted" questions. Some of them are displayed in red - some of which I have recently visited - but not all. What does "red" mean?

Comment: What exactly is red? The title? The whole row? The number of views? Also maybe you have visited them so long ago that you don't even remember? (for example, I keep surprising myself by finding a brilliant answer to something that interested me, and then failing to upvote it, because it turns out that it was my own answer...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Red links are pages that you have already visited. Click on one that is not red and then go back just to test. Clear your browser cache if you are finding ones that you don't remember visiting.

Comment: Thats it - thx (strange how I don't remember some questions :-))

Answer (score 10):

[image]